# What type conversions exist in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

[Slot](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/Slot.html), [Signal](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/Signal.html), [Property](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_UsingQtProperties), etc. take a type.  For instance, the sample code shows:

```py
class MyObject(QObject):                                                                            

    def __init__(self,startval=42):                                                                 
        QObject.__init__(self)                                                                      
        self.ppval = startval                                                                       
                                                                                                   
    def readPP(self):                                                                                   
        return self.ppval                                                                               
                                                                                                    
    def setPP(self,val):                                                                                
        self.ppval = val                                                                                
                                                           
    pp = Property(int, readPP, setPP)  # <--- Look at the first argument
```

The `Property` expects an 'int'.

What types are possible?  I can find no documentation.

In my time working with Qt, I have gleaned the following through osmosis:

- int
- float
- bool
- str
- list
- 'QVariant'
- 'QJsonObject`

Are these the only types available?  Are they actually documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it supports any data type.

The problem is that if QML supports it, and in that case there are only some basic types that PySide/PyQt can interpret and convert them to QML objects. Unfortunately there is no documentation about it (maybe reporting it as a bug would be good for them to implement it).

Besides the ones you indicate you can also use:

- "QVariantList"
- QObject: this type must also be exported when you expose models or classes derived from QObject.
- QColor
- QUrl
- QDateTime
- QFont
- QPoint, QPointF
- QRect, QRectF
- QSize, QSizeF

In theory PySide/PyQt can support at most the types that Qt/C++ supports and in that case if there is documentation about it:  [Basic Qt Data Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#basic-qt-data-types).

Any other type of python data that is not in that list will be encapsulated in a QVariant since it does support [PyObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject) but it will be unusable since it cannot be manipulated in QML.